# Remove clearly and reinstall python on CentOS

Tags: python, centos, rpm, yum

Today I messed up the versions of Python on my CentOS machine. Even `yum` cannot work properly. I made the mistake that I removed the default `/usr/bin/python` which led to this situation. How could I get back a clear Python environment? I thought remove them totally and reinstall Python may work, but do not know how to do it. Wish somebody could help!

Comment: You just deleted `/usr/bin/python`? if so, copy it from another machine

Comment: What exactly did you do? You simply replace that executable with a different python executable? There are also executables there that should be named for the specific version of Python, e.g. `/usr/bin/python2.6` (in CentOS 6) -- You can try copying that file to `/usr/bin/python` assuming you did not overwrite those as well.

Comment: I deleted the default `/usr/bin/python` and made a soft link `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.7`. I think copying one from another machine would help.

Comment: Dont try this, or you'll end up buying this: http://www.keepcalmstudio.com/gallery/poster/1BLAEVH

Comment: luckily, it's just a virtual machine, thx bro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `yum` package manager is relies on an underlying tool called `rpm`, which does not require Python.  You can use that to re-install the system Python package.

You can use this to reinstall the base `python` package from a CentOS mirror:

```
rpm -ivh --replacepkgs --replacefiles http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
```

For example:

```
# rm -f /usr/bin/python*
# yum version
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
# rpm -ivh --replacefiles --replacepkgs http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DCR7QF: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:python                 ########################################### [100%]
# yum version
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Installed: 6/x86_64                 131:0e17bede37a026e5f95d6cb7e185701b989fa47d
Group-Installed: yum                 14:973b685dc3deb5d8f00cdb3ec97022064b5ff793
version
```

Comment: @OscarJavierJimenez, I think you have misunderstood this answer. This does not remove the base Python. It *reinstalls* the base python after it has been removed or replaced, as in the original question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to answer another question in another post. Sorry, it was late.

Comment: this is probably not a valid solution since the OP mentioned that yum is not working

Comment: @MayAnneLuyun The reason this answer uses `rpm` instead of `yum` is because `yum` requires Python, but `rpm` does not.

Answer (score -1):

To install Python on CentOS: sudo yum install python2/3 (select the version as per requirement)
To uninstall Python on CentOS: sudo yum remove python2/3 (select the version as per your requirement)
To check version for python3(which you installed): python3 --version
To check version for python2 (which you installed): python2 --version

Comment: This is not a valid solution because OP indicated they are unable to use yum.